# GCP Stackdriver logging: How to put logs in "Global" section?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have gone though documentation for installing [stackdriver agent on linux](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration).

With similar configuration as below of fluentd

```
$ cat /etc/google-fluentd/config.d/test-structured-log.conf
<source>
    @type tail
    format json
    path /tmp/test-structured-log.log
    pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/test-structured-log.pos
    read_from_head true
    tag structured-log
</source>
```

But my logs are shown in "**GCE VM Instace > My-Instance > structured-log**"

I'm not able to find documentation where I can set logs in **"Global"** resource as shown below.

[image]

How can I configure my linux instance to put logs in **Global**?

Comment: Using Cloud SDK 'gcloud logging write' https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk

Comment: Thanks for input, but I'm using google-fluentd service for logging & can not put `logger` command in application

Comment: Have you tried setting labels, not sure if it's possible to set "type":"global" to override the value, but no hard in trying. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#label-setup

Comment: If I may ask ... what is the thinking on flagging the type of the Log Entry to be Global as opposed to the current gce_instance?  It seems to me that the log entry does come from a gce_instance as opposed to anything else.  Maybe we are solving the wrong puzzle?

Comment: Want to accumulate all logs from gce and vm instances in one place, possibly in one tag

Comment: Do you mean "accumulate" in the logs viewer, or somewhere else?  You can select all instances at once, even if the logs are associated with one VM specifically. You might also try https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters and only specifying the log name (structured-log).

Comment: I would like to have for Google app engines + VM's + other services in single tag

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, what you want to do is change the resource type associated to your logs entries. Now Stackdriver is showing exactly the right resource, "GCE VM Instace > Instance-Name > structured-log" so in my opinion that’s the best decision. [Global](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types), is a resource type used to indicate that a log is not associated with any specific resource.

If you still want to change it, you will have to explicitly set the resource on your logs entries. See [1](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) and [2](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry).